# golang package local does not find

Tags: go

I can not import a package of mine.

I have already used go mod init but it does not work. Content of go.mod:

```
module github.com/grafeno30/golang_redes/rat

go 1.13
```

My project has the following structure:

```
github.com/grafeno30/golang_redes/
├── rat
│   ├── client
│   │   └── main.go
│   ├── server
│   │   ├── core
│   │   │   └── handleConnection
│   │   │       └── establishedConnection.go
│   │   ├── main.go
│   │   └── server
│   ├── go.mod
│   └── go.sum
└── README.md
```

When I execute `go build .` in the folder **"github.com/grafeno30/golang_redes/rat/server"** I get the following error:

```
# github.com/grafeno30/golang_redes/rat/server
./main.go:14:13: undefined: handleConnection
```

In summary, I use a function of the module **rat/server/core/handleConnection** in the main go file **rat/server/main.go**

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, I import "github.com/grafeno30/golang_redes/rat/server/core/handleConnection" but I get the message: "github.com/grafeno30/golang_redes/rat/server/core/handleConnection" imported but not used as handleconnectioncompiler

Comment: Hello Cerise, I have renamed the folder and file to handlerconnectioncompiler but how I have to impor the package? I use ""github.com/grafeno30/golang_redes/rat/server/core/handleConnection" but it does not work. Tanks

Comment: When I execute "go build .", I get the next error mesage:
can't load package: package .: no Go files in /home/transistor47/workspace/go/src/github.com/grafeno30/golang_redes/rat. I import ""handleconnectioncompiler" and I use handleconnectioncompiler.ConnectWithWindows(IP, PORT)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out

I have had to use: go mod, go mod init, go mod edit -replace and go mod tidy.

Basically I have made a replacement "go mod edit -replace github.com/grafeno30/golang_redes/rat/server/core/handler=./core/handler"

Thank you all!!!